# Replacing old abs with new

Tags: plumbing

[image]Hey mike here I'm trying to fix a leaking pipe in my basement. I just need to ask and see if yall can help me on what i need to buy to replace the whole piece. Ill post sum picks and Please let me know what yall think
I know its ABS i know i need different cleaner and glue not PVC stuff but abs just not sure on the couplers and all help thanks

Comment: You want to replace all pieces in the picture?  no cleaner just abs glue.  Your fittings are 4" going down to 2".  So the 4x4x2 y and 4" 45degree?

Comment: Where is it leaking from? Are you sure you have to replace all that?

Comment: The 2 sliver marks on the pipe is the part i want to fix its leaking at the 2 in part and just want to make sure i get all the stuff